# Использование style внутри другого style в ресурсах Android приложения

Tags: android, style, ресурсы

Для приложения определен стайлгайд, в данном случае дизайнер определил конкретный стиль для некоторых текстов. Этот же стиль текста используется внутри кнопок, которые тоже стилизованы.

Могу ли я создавая стиль для кнопки использовать в качестве одного из айтемов готовый стиль, а не добавлять заново все параметры?

Пытался через `textAppearance`, но компилятор не желает это прожёвывать

**UPDATED**

Всё таки прожёвывает. Это моя ошибка, делал через `textAppearance`, а нужно было через `android:textAppearance`